# rerender output panel to display the update list

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have a page that iterates a list object to display the records. Once clicked on save, I updated the same list with new values and debug logs shows the update list but output panel is not rerender'ed  and I dont see updated list on VF page.

```
<apex:outputLabel >A  </apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputfield id="idAText" value="{!ttlookup.A}" />
      <apex:inputCheckbox id="checkBoxTMId" value="{!Acheckbox}"/>
      <apex:outputLabel > Check if you want to clear all values 
</apex:outputLabel>

    <apex:commandButton id="btnSave" value=" Save " action="{!Save}" reRender="idPanel" />

 <apex:outputPanel ID = "idPanel">
        <div class="container">   
            <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Type</th> 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!ryList}" var="tt">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{!tt.name}</td>
                                    <td>{!tt.Type__c}</td>
                                </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
```

Controller code:

```
 public void save(){
    Boolean noUpdateFlag = false;
    for(MyObjec ttry: ryList){
        if(ttlookup.A !=null){
            noUpdateFlag = true;
            ttry.name = ttlookup.A;
        }

        if(Acheckbox){
            noUpdateFlag = true;
            ttry.name = null;
        }

    }
    system.debug(ryList[0].B + ' noUpdateFlag '+noUpdateFlag);
    try{
        if(noUpdateFlag){
            update ryList;
            ApexPages.addmessage(new Apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.CONFIRM, 'records are saved.'));
        }
        else
            ApexPages.addmessage(new Apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.Info, 'no value entered '));
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.debug(ex);
        ApexPages.addmessage(new Apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.Error, 'Something went wrong'));
    }

}
```

and moreover when I add reRender = "id.." my apex messages are not displayed. I have no clue why :(
any inputs please?

Comment: Share controller code as well.

Comment: @TusharSharma I have updated  the post

Comment: Where are you updating `name , Type__c` in save method?

Comment: @PragatiJain ttry.A = ttlookup.A; this how i am updating. ryList that displays in UI. I have also update post

Comment: On UI you are iterating `ryList` and displaying `name` and `Type__c` field but in save method you are not updating the values of these fields. How can you predict that rerender is not working?

Comment: @PragatiJain ryList is displaying before the save() called. Once save() is called, i want the panel to rerender the list . I AM UPDATING THE LIST

Comment: can you please add `<td>{!tt.A}</td>` inside `<apex:repeat>`.  After saving code test the page and provide value in `A` lookup and then click on save button and check

Comment: @PragatiJain I updated the code to avoid confusion, what you asked is already in the code.

Comment: Thanks @PragatiJain You are right I wasn't updating the list. found the issue and fixed it. please post I will mark it

Comment: I am happy to help you! I have added an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VF page code looks good. Rerender should work properly. It looks like you are not updating the list. So please update the list in a proper way and check the result.

Comment: I was update it but It contains only ID not the name so I had to query and update the list by name and type. It worked now. It strick my mind when you commented that I might not have updated the list. Thanks @Pragati Jain